# Cannot update Elasticbeanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I am using `public UpdateEnvironmentResult updateEnvironment(UpdateEnvironmentRequest updateEnvironmentRequest)` methos of  `AWSElasticBeanstalkClient` from my EC2instance but gets the following error

```
com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.InsufficientPrivilegesException: You do not have permission to perform the 's3:CreateBucket' action. Verify that your S3 policies and your ACLs allow you to perform these actions. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InsufficientPrivilegesException; Request ID: 412d8fab-0cfe-11e6-928e-e1e1532d705e)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1389)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.doInvoke(AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.java:2223)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.invoke(AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.java:2193)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.updateEnvironment(AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.java:2093)
```

My IAM role doesn't have access for s3:create bucket. But why does it need to create bucket? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is uploading the application source bundle to S3.

Give your instance `AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier` policy permission. That will give you instance access to buckets called elasticbeanstalk* only, which what the SDK will name the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me recently after I updated the policy of a Lambda function, from the deprecated `AWSLambdaFullAccess` to `AWSLambda_FullAccess`. If you are also using a SAM template for deploying your Lambda functions, extend the permissions by adding this to your template:

```yaml
LambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Timeout: 270
    Policies:
      - AWSLambda_FullAccess
      - AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy
```